# Does em in margin and padding take font size as a reference point?

Tags: css, font-size

In the code below, do `margins` on `p` and `h2` take their respective `font-size` as  reference point?

How about `margin` and `padding` on `div.contact`? What do they take their reference point as? Is it the body `font-size`?

```
body { font-size: 100%; }
p { font-size: 1em; margin-bottom:0.5em; }
h2 { font-size: 2em; margin-bottm:1em; }
div.contact { margin: 1.5em 0; padding: 0 0.7em; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the margin and padding in ems are based on the parents font-size.

Let say that you have this markup:

```
<div class="contact">
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

You have a body font-size of 100%, so it's the browser standard font-size, for easiness let's say 16px. (Imo you shouldn't convert em to px in your mind, but change you way of thinking to em-based. Just to make you help understand I do convert it in the code below)

For `div.contact` that means:

```
div.contact { 
   margin: 1.5em 0; /* 16 x 1.5 = 24px */
   padding: 0 0.7em; /* 16 x 0.7 = 11.2px */
}
```

For the `h2` that means:

```
h2 {
   font-size: 2em; /* 16 x 2 = 32px */
   margin-bottm:1em; /* 16 x 2 x 1 = 32px */
}
```

For example, if you change the font-size from `.contact` to lets say 1.2em this will happen:

```
div.contact { 
   font-size: 1.5em; /* 16 x 1.2 = 19.2px */
   margin: 1.5em 0; /* 16 x 1.2 x 1.5 = 28.8px */
   padding: 0 0.7em; /* 16 x 1.2 x 0.7 = 13.44px */
}
h2 {
   font-size: 2em; /* 16 x 1.2 x 2 = 38.4px */
   margin-bottm:1em; /* 16 x 1.2 x 2 x 1 = 38.4px */
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

In `div.contact` 1em is from current div's font-size, it this situation it means `100%` declared in `body`.

Another situation:

```
<style>
    body {font-size: 100%:}
    #wrapper {font-size: 120%;}
    .contact {margin: 1em} /* 1em regarding font-size 120% */
</style>

<div id=wrapper>
    <div class=contact>contact</div>
</div>
```